# What is the best way to set up an angularjs project with old javascript files, typescript and sourcemap?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, gulp, source-maps

I would like to use a bootstrap-template with js-files for my new angularjs project. New modules will be written in typescript.

So my idea was to transcipt all ts files into `/build/js/`
Then i would concat all js files from `/app/**/*.js` and from `/build/**/*.js` into app.js.

My project folder structure looks like this.

```
app
|-js-files
|-ts-files
build
 |js folder with .js.map.files
|-app.js
|-app.js.map
|-vendor.js
```

On every step sourcemap files will be created.
There are my gulp tasks:

```
gulp.task('typescript', function () {
  var tsResult = tsProject.src()
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())  // sourcemaps will be generated
    .pipe(tsProject());

  return tsResult.js
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.')) // Now the sourcemaps are added to the .js file
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js'));
});

gulp.task('bundle', function () {
  return es.merge(gulp.src(source.js.src), getTemplateStream())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) // sourcemaps will be generated
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.')) // Now the sourcemaps are added to the .js file
    .pipe(gulp.dest(destinations.js));
});
```

1. Is this the right way to set up a project like this?
2. Source mapping doesn't work...?
3. Should the folder `/build/js` be deleted after the bundling into app.js?

Comment: i found the point, why sourcemapping wasn't working after bundling

adding loadMaps: true on the bundling process fixed this issue
    
`.pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))`

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the right way to set up a project like this

Personally no. Have all the files `.js` and `.ts` in the same folder `./src`. Set `allowJs:true` and `outDir:'./dist'`. Then slowly start the `.js` -> `.ts` migration as needed.

## More

As an example checkout this quick video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gmKXXI_ck7w

Comment: After bundling i can't debug the original ts files. What is wrong?